# How can I locate my import in node_modules

Tags: angular

In one of my npm based project, I am using this below import:

```
import { FooService, BarService } from '@blah/heck-yeah';
```

Since I am from Java Background and new to Angular, I want to know the internal of what I am importing exactly. So when I went in `node_modules/blah/` and COULD NOT find anything having having name as `heck-yeah`.

**Question:** Where can I locate `heck-yeah` in above scenario. I am feeling kinda feeling completely lost here. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using VSCode, click on it or ‘Shift+Enter’ and it should take you there.

Comment: Yeah I am using VSCode. More confusion now, it took me to this path - `/some/path/my-angular-app/projects/aca-shared/src/lib/services/some-api.service.ts`. Then why I have to do - `@blah/heck-yeah`? Whats going on here? Any relevant information where I can read and learn more about the imports?

Comment: A service file has different functions or services that can perform calls, that is communicate with the backend. So once you write the GET/POST calls in a service file, you need to import them to your component to make whatever calls that are required. For example- this.foorService.getFoo(). You need to import the service first, which is exactly what it’s doing.